# createReceiver isn't a function

Tags: discord.js

I need some help. The bot joins the voice channel but then crashes when I speak into the voice channel. I am trying to receive voice packets then tell the console that I received packets. The error that I get when speaking is:

```html
(node:1394) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: voiceConnection.createReceiver is not a function
(node:1394) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1394) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code is here:

```html
  if (command == 'record') {
      message.member.voice.channel.join().then((voiceConnection) => {

const { Readable } = require('stream');

const SILENCE_FRAME = Buffer.from([0xF8, 0xFF, 0xFE]);

class Silence extends Readable {
  _read() {
    this.push(SILENCE_FRAME);
  }
}

// Plays silence infinitely
voiceConnection.play(new Silence(), { type: 'opus' });
            const receiver = voiceConnection.createReceiver();

            voiceConnection.on("speaking",
                (user, speaking) => {
                    if (speaking) {
                        const audioStream = receiver.createStream(user);

                        audioStream.on('data',
                            (chunk) => {
                                console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
                            });
                    } 
                });


        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In discord.js v12, `VoiceConnection#createReciever()` was removed in favor of `VoiceConnection#reciever`. I imagine this is because they wanted to limit you to one receiver instead of letting you create however many you want, but I'm not certain. I'm sure you can find a reason in the release notes.

Comment: Do you have any documentation I can read perhaps? I have been searching all over the web...

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=receiver